# Python App Engine Backend working for cron but not if I hit url directly

Tags: python, google-app-engine, backend

We have a script that takes some time to execute. We have scheduled a cron job and use backend to run the job.

Here's what the cron looks like:
`url: /cron/my_job_name

target: mybackend

schedule: every 30 minutes from 06:00 to 12:00`

The cron job runs correctly as expected. But when I hit the url:
https://myappname.googleplex.com/cron/my_job_name
I get a "DeadlineExceededError" when the job runs for more than 60 seconds.

I need to be able to hit the url directly for testing purposes. I don't want to change the cron schedule every time for testing.

Is there a way to run the backend by hitting the url?

Adding my app.yaml and backends.yaml

**app.yaml**
`url: /cron/my_job_name

  script: path/my_job_name.py

  login: admin`

**backends.yaml**
`name: mybackend

  class: B8

  instances: 1

  options: dynamic`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like when you are hitting your URL, you are not actually invoking a backend instance to handle it.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview#Addressing_Backends):

> A backend instance can be targeted with HTTP requests to
>   http://[instance].[backend_name].[your_app_id].appspot.com, or at your
>   application's custom domain. If you target a backend without targeting
>   an instance using http://[backend_name].[your_app_id].appspot.com, App
>   Engine selects the first available instance of the backend.
>
> The Backends API provides functions to retrieve the address of a
>   backend or instance. This allows application versions to target
>   backends with requests, for a backend to target another backend, or
>   for one instance of a backend to target another instance. This works
>   in both the development and production environments.
>
> The BACKEND_ID and INSTANCE_ID environment variables contain the
>   backend name and instance index of the instance handling the request.

Modify your url to include your backend name (from you backends.yaml) and you should be able to access it, provided other configs are correct.

More on that same topic:

> Backends share the handlers defined in app.yaml with the main
>   application version. You can place your backends in a separate
>   application root directory if you want to avoid sharing code or
>   handlers, or simply mark the relevant handlers with login: admin.

It might be helpful if you posted your backends.yaml, app.yaml and handlers if you would like a more in depth answer.

Comment: @TanvirShaikh, I'll try to reconstruct that later today and see what might be an issue... however, I'm not sure why you are using "googolplex.com"... is this for an internal google app?

Comment: @TanvirShaikh I'll ask around to see if anyone knows the difference from the public version. I'm not affiliated with Google, so don't know their internal stuff.